# Setting up Mail Server for multiple domains mapped to different ip addresses

Tags: server, email, postfix, ip, mail

We have taken dedicated hosting and using it for hosting multiple domains.

The different domains are mapped to different ip addresses.

for example

```
example1.com mapped to 1.0.0.1
```

and

```
example2.com mapped to 1.0.0.2
```

1.0.0.1 was the ip address that came initially with the hosting and we purchased and added another ip 1.0.0.2 later.

Right now postfix has been set up to deliver mails and configuration has been done in

/etc/postfix/virtual

to send mail for both domains to the same account (user1) like below:

```
webmaster@example1.com user1
webmaster@example2.com user1
```

The additional ip address were added using netplan by editing the 01-netcfg.yaml file as follows:

```
#This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
#For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: yes
      addresses: [1.0.0.1/22, 1.0.0.2/22, 69.64.50.12/22]
```

PROBLEM: The mail only arrives when sent to webmaster@example1.com i.e. the domain mapped to initial ip address 1.0.0.1 and not to webmaster@example2.com mapped to the additional ip address - 1.0.0.2

As already stated
1.0.0.1, 1.0.0.2 are just example ip addresses here

Comment: Please add relevant details. What do you mean by "mapped to"? Show your exact DNS entries. What do you mean by "does not arrive"? Is there an error message? Do you get a non-delivery message (aka bounce)? What does the Postfix log show in the case ot the mail not arriving? And, on a different track: why did you assign different IP addresses in the first place? What do you want to achieve by that?

Comment: There should be something in `/var/log/mail.log` showing that a message was received. If there isn’t, you’ll want to confirm that port 25 is not blocked for that second IP address 